# Python, print a letter n times on an nth iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I seem to be stumped on this one. Unfortunately, I'm not even sure how to explain what I want. For n iterations in a loop, I want to print a letter n times. Here's some starter code...

```
n = 1
max = 3

letters = string.lowecase
letters.split

while n <= max:
    for letter in letters:
        print letter #n times
    n = n + 1
```

I would like to end up with:

a
b
...
z
aa
...
zz
aaa
...
zzz

Comment: The question is already answered, so just a note: the pythonic way to iterate over a range is `for n in xrange(max):...`, then you don't need the last line `n = n + 1`.

Comment: This is covered _very well_ by the [standard Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: Ah, I understand xrange() now. I was lacking the vocabulary to figure out what I needed from the standard python tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print j * i
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings can be multiplied.

```
>>> 'foo' * 4
'foofoofoofoo'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.ascii_lowercase

>>> print("".join( x*n for n in range(1,4) for x in letters  ))

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzzaaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrssstttuuuvvvwwwxxxyyyzzz
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another loop:

```
# Prints the letters
for letter in letters:
        print letter

# Prints each letter 3 times:
for letter in letters:
    for i in xrange(3):
        print letter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 1
max = 3

letters = string.lowecase
letters.split

while n <= max:
    for letter in letters:
        print letter * n
    n = n + 1
```

multiply works with strings

Answer (score 0):

Other way of doing

`(lambda s: ''.join([x*n for n in xrange(4) for x in s]))(letters)`